# JRuby rspec: How to use --debug option for complete coverage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, jruby, simplecov

when i issue following command

```
 jruby -S rspec
```

It run with following warning

C:/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/simplecov-0.7.1/lib/simplecov.rb:34 
warning: tracing (e.g. set_trace_func) will not capture all events without --debug
flag

So here my question is how to use this --debug option while running rspec

Answer (score 0):

I'm running simplecov (0.8.2) with JRuby 1.7.11 and I'm not having an issue. Here's my setup:

.rspec:

```
 --format documentation
 --color
```

In the spec_helper.rb:

```
require 'simplecov'
SimpleCov.start 'rails'
```

Whether I run the default rake task with:

```
jruby -S bundle exec rake
```

Or run rspec as you did, I get the debug warning. However simplecov still actually works just fine. I can see the coverage of the various files.

Comment: Yeah i seem to be getting that as well on my views. Interesting. The views do look covered just fine, as I have a fair number of integration tests.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have got the solution:
When I executing rspec without --debug option

```
jruby -S rspec
```

It give me coverage of **97.8%**

And with --debug

```
jruby --debug -S rspec
```

It give me coverage of **98.46%**

And I have also confirmed with ruby using

```
bundle exec rspec
```

It give me coverage result **98.36%**

So I think using --debug option is better option.

If you don't want warning like 
Warning: coverage data provided by Coverage [7] exceeds number of lines

Then you can add following lines to simplecov config block

```
SimpleCov.start 'rails' do
  add_filter 'app/views'
end
```